# Combining two lists of pandas series:1) one containing historical time series, and 2) another containing forecast time series

Tags: python, pandas, series

These two lists contain the same series of data with df_hist_list representing the historical series and forecast_list containing the forecasts.  I would like to combine the two series where the result is a list of the two components together (i.e. df_Cash_DF_history and Cash_Due_From_Banks combined result in the full series together as one series).

```
df_hist_list=[df_Cash_DF_history,df_Int_Dep_w_Banks_history,df_Corp_Sec_history,\
              df_USGovt_Agency_history,df_Muni_history,df_Unreal_G_L_history,\
              ...
              df_Furn_Equip_Exp_history,df_Data_Proc_Exp_history,df_Promo_Exp_history,\
              df_Oth_Op_Exp_history,df_ORE_Exp_history,df_Inc_Tax_Exp_history]


forecast_list=[Cash_Due_From_Banks,Int_Bear_Dep_w_Banks,Corp_Sec,USGovt_Agency,\
               Muni,Unreal_Gain_Loss,RE_Loans,Pers_Loans,Ag_Loans,Bus_Loans,\
               ...
               Emp_Ben_Exp,Occ_Exp,Furn_Equip_Exp,Data_Proc_Exp,Promo_Exp,\
               Oth_Op_Exp,ORE_Exp,Inc_Tax_Exp]

df_Cash_DF_history
Out[114]: 
Q1_2018    8739244.00
Q2_2018    5698279.00
Q3_2018    8849542.00
Q4_2018    1503914.00
Q1_2019    7417558.00
Q2_2019    6000285.00
Q3_2019    8697910.00
Name: TOTAL CASH & DUE FROM BANKS, dtype: object

Cash_Due_From_Banks
Out[115]: 
Q3_2019   28,697,910
Q4_2019   27,810,123
Q1_2020   26,937,969
Q2_2020   26,081,183
Q3_2020   25,239,505
Q4_2020   24,412,679
Q1_2021   23,600,453
Q2_2021   22,802,580
Q3_2021   22,018,816
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that each DataFrame has one column and what you presented as *Quarter*
column is actually the **index**.

Let's start form the case of 2 DataFrames.

To take the leftmost column from such two DataFrames, and concatenate
them vertically into a *Series*, define the following function:

```
def myConcat(df1, df2):
    s = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:,0], df2.iloc[:,0]])
    return s[~s.index.duplicated()]
```

I noticed that your 2 DataFrames have one row from the same quarter, so there
is a need to eliminate such repetitions, and to this end I used
*index.duplicated()*.

Then, e.g. for both source DataFrames which you presented, call it:

```
myConcat(df_Cash_DF_history, Cash_Due_From_Banks)
```

And to process 2 **lists** of DataFrames and generate a **list** of *Series*
objects, resulting from pairwise concatenation, run:

```
[ myConcat(df1, df2) for df1, df2 in zip(df_hist_list, forecast_list) ]
```